# Creating custom shaped(non rectangular) button & button set with a new clickable area & frame

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, uibutton, uibezierpath

I'm creating a circular shaped button set which is formed by 6 triangles buttons and looks like below.

[image: Circular shaped button set]

Each triangle is a different button.
To create that circular shape, I've created 6 different layers of triangle buttons in top of each and rotated every single of them by adding +60 degrees consecutively(Detailed explanation below). Since the rotation happens right in viewdidload, I can't get this circular shape without launching simulator.

The triangle shaped buttons looks like below without launching the simulator. I know it looks like a single triangle button but there are 5 more same buttons underneath it(so 6 buttons in total). To give them circular shape I've rotated each by adding 60 degrees.(also with an anchor point)

So the first image is rotated 0 degrees, the second is 60, third is 120 and so on.. That's how I get the circular shape with triangle buttons.

[image]

I've also set triangle clickable area for each triangle(by using BezierPath) so only the triangle image is being clickable. But the frame of the buttons are still rectangle as below.

[image]

My problem is, when I get the circular shape, the last triangle's frame overlaps the first button. so even tho the clickable area is triangle, due to frame(which is rectangle) it blocks the clickable area of the button that is right near it. Is there any possible way that I can crop the frame of a button to a custom shape that I want? or it always has to be rectangle? how can I solve my problem of overlapping frames due to circular shape?

I'm open to any kind of solution, even if it is about creating that circular shaped button set in another way.

My code blocks are as below.

***Codes:***

Rotation func with a new anchor point:

```
 func rotateButton(button : UIButton, angle : Double) {
    
    button.setAnchorPoint(CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1))// setting new anchor
    button.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(angle * Double.pi/180))
}
```

Increasing the rotation angle by 60 degrees for each triangle button:

```
 for buttons in buttonArray {
    
        rotateButton(button: buttons, angle: degree)
    degree = degree + 60
        }
```

Setting the triangle shaped clickable area Class for the buttons(then setting the buttons' class to this new class):

```
class triangleShapeButton: UIButton {
private let triangle = UIBezierPath()

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        triangle.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: rect.height))
        triangle.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:rect.width/2, y: 0))
        triangle.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y:rect.height))
        triangle.close()

    }

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        // This is for allow touches only in shape area.
        if triangle.contains(touches.first?.location(in: self) ?? .zero) {
            super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think the easy way to create 6 triangles inside one single button and make a 6 different UIBezierPath() and inside the touchesBegan check the bezier path and identify the correct rectangle.

Comment: Hi raja. So basically, i should create 6 different bezierpaths for an image but how can I identify if the correct triangle was clicked? And how can I give different tasks to each of those triangles? Thanks